# How to iterate through array to find C-style string

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

> Write a function, char* findx(const char* s, const char* x), that finds the
> first occurrence of the C-style string x in s. Do not use any standard library functions. Do not use subscripting; use the dereference operator *
> instead.

For my current purposes, I'm using the constraints of the prompt rather loosely. What I currently have is very rough code to find the occurrence of the string, but I'm having trouble with pointer arithmetic to be able to output the matching word. Because of the way I constructed my for loop, the output omits the first letter. Furthermore, I'm using a variable outside my for loop to increment my pointer, which I want to avoid. Any ideas on how I can improve this? I know there's better ways to approach this, but I wanted to see if I can improve this without significantly altering the for loop.

```
const char* findx(const char* s, const char* x)
{
  int size = strlen(s);
  int size1 = strlen(x);
  int n = 1;

  for (const char* p = &s[0]; p < &s[size]; ++p) {
    if (*p == *x) {
      for (const char* j = &x[1]; j < &x[size1]; ++j) {
        if (*j == *(p+n)) {
          cout << *j;
          ++n;
        }
    }
   }
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: *"Do not use subscripting"*, so replace `&s[size]` by `s + size`.

Comment: While you're waiting for answers, I'll offer a couple suggestions to make the code more readable. `size` and `size1` are confusing variable names. It would be clearer if their names reflect their purpose, e.g. something like `sizeS` and `sizeX`. Similarly, the names `p` and `j` are a bit confusing; 'j' is conventionally used for indexing, and again the names don't reflect their purpose. Lastly, `&s[0]` is just 's', and you could use pointer arithmetic instead of indexing for the other values. Making some changes along those lines might make the code easier to analyze.

Comment: That link for [`std::search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) provides possible implementation.

Comment: I would imagine that the purpose of having a `const char *` return type is to return a pointer to the string if it is found. You are only returning `nullptr`.

Comment: Could you please add an example with current behavior and expected behavior?